# Which is more stable out of the given carbocation?

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbocation

> Which is more stable?
>
> 1. $\ce{^+C(CH3)3}$
> 2. $\ce{^+C(CD3)3}$

I have read in Solomon's and Fryhle that the +I effect of D is more than that of H but here in this problem it is given that $\ce{(CH3)3C+}$ is more stable.

How is this possible? Since, deuterium enriches the electron density over the central carbon resulting in the diminishing of a positive charge eventually making the second structure more stable.

Second explanation can be on the basis of hyperconjugation which says that $\ce{-CH3}$ is better in showing hyperconjugation than $\ce{-CD3}$, but why is this so?

Answer (score 4):

$\ce{C-D}$ bonds are stronger. Hyperconjugation is thus more easily seen  with hydrogen rather than deuterium.
   **Hyperconjugation> Inductive effects** at stabilization.I believe you can reason the rest out by yourself. 
 To see why $\ce{C-D}$ bonds are stronger. 

[See this](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/70128/why-is-a-c-d-bond-stronger-than-a-c-h-bond)

Comment: While true, this answer is extremely unsatisfying. The link from bond strength to hyperconjugation is not obvious to me at all. (And I'm not saying I have any better explanation. This is something which I have never seen a good explanation for.)

Comment: @orthocresol Maybe [this](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0040402059801095) contains the required answer.