# Classic/killer/easy application for the deuterium kinetic isotope effect?

Tags: bond, stability, isotope

I'm a physicist. While visiting someone's o-chem class I learned about the existence of the deuterium kinetic isotope effect. This seems like an extremely sweet example of zero-point energy, and I would like to use it as an example when teaching the basic quantum mechanics that we teach in freshman physics at a community college.

In this context, I would like to be able to give a good example where we actually care about the deuterium kinetic isotope effect. Ideally this would be an example that would be at least somewhat understandable to people who (like me) have no clue about organic chemistry. Something like:

- Without the deuterium kinetic isotope effect, we wouldn't be able to synthesize x (where x is nail polish, fullerenes, methamphetamine, ...)
- Historically, there was intense controversy about how this mysterious chemical process in x worked (where x is learning in slime molds, work-hardening of bronze, ...), but then they injected their (slime mold, ...) with deuterium and used the deuterium kinetic isotope effect to prove that ...

Related: [Why is a C–D bond stronger than a C–H bond?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/70128/why-is-a-c-d-bond-stronger-than-a-c-h-bond)

Comment: Involvement of water in enzyme-based catalysis, I'm sure there are examples.

Comment: The effect can be smaller that you imagine as the energy at the transition state may also be lowered so the barrier height need not change that much. In reactions involving many steps, particularly with enzymes a small, say 10%, change at each step becomes important and results in a big overall effect.

Comment: You might read about heavy water toxicity to find an overall impressive one. For instance an aquarium of heavy water can host no fishes, at least after a certain time.

Comment: @porphyrin "Big" is relative. I dont think there is a natural reaction pathway that can actually *accumulate* deuterium in a specific chemical function to twice the concentration in the surrounding water or so. Much less, usually.

Comment: The site specific hydrogen (and carbon) isotope ratios tell you if the alcohol in your wine was actually made by fermentation of fructose (instead of saccharose, maltose, ...), and even if the fructose was actually in grapes and not apples. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotopic_analysis_by_nuclear_magnetic_resonance.

Comment: @Karl, Sure, 'big' is relative, but I meant only that if hydrogen was replaced with deuterium then the effect would be accumulative and so much slower.

Comment: @porphyrin A hydrogen atom can only be replaced by deuterium once. ;) Where du you see an accumulative slowing effect?

Comment: @Karl, quite so but in a sequence $A \to B \to C\cdots$  each step is slower so slower overall.

Comment: @Alchimista: Your comment sounds like it would make a good answer.

Comment: An expensive but possible demo would be to make two candles, one out of perdeuterated wax, and another out of regular wax, and to burn them both at the same time.  The rate at which the candles burn should be significantly different.